# Time In and Time Out Query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How to query mysql, time duration of my (time in) and (out) with two different dates. for example Saturday 06-06-2020  10:00 PM time in and my time out Sunday 07-06-2020  6:00 AM my time out...,
for Night Duties?

DATABASE :
[image]

EXAMPLE RESULT:

```
---------------------------------------
|Date| HOURS    | DUTY  | TIME        |
|               |       |             |
|6-7 | 8 hours  | NIGHT | 10pm - 6am  |
|7-8 | 8 hours  | NIGHT | 10pm - 6am  |
|8-9 | 8 hours  | NIGHT | 10pm - 6am  |
|10  | 8 hours  | DAY   | 8am - 5pm   |
|11  | 8 hours  | DAY   | 8am - 5pm   |
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: you mean ,getting first and second row at the same time? then 3rd and 4th row ? ...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RaRa yes, I need to get time in and out but in different rows.... see my database for reference and my example result.

Answer (score 0):

SET @row_number1 = 0; 
SET @row_number2 = 0;

SELECT (IF(DATE_FORMAT(timein,'%d') = DATE_FORMAT(timeout,'%d') ,DATE_FORMAT(timein,'%d') ,CONCAT_WS('-',DATE_FORMAT(timein,'%d'),DATE_FORMAT(timeout,'%d')))) as day, timein,timeout,(TIMEDIFF(timeout,timein)) as time_duration
FROM

(SELECT tbl1.timein, tbl2.timeout FROM

(SELECT (@row_number1:=@row_number1 + 1) AS num,timein  FROM(
SELECT
(case when DwInOutMode = 0 then DATE_FORMAT(DateTimeRecord,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') else Null end) as timein
from biologs where IndRegID = 3 AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOnlyRecord,'%m/%Y') = '06/2020') as tbletimein WHERE timein IS NOT NULL) as tbl1

JOIN

(SELECT (@row_number2:=@row_number2 + 1) AS num,timeout  FROM(
SELECT
(case when DwInOutMode = 1 then DATE_FORMAT(DateTimeRecord,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') else Null end) as timeout
from biologs where IndRegID = 3 AND DATE_FORMAT(DateOnlyRecord,'%m/%Y') = '06/2020') as tbletimein WHERE timeout IS NOT NULL) as tbl2

ON tbl1.num = tbl2.num) as tbl_payroll

Answer (score -1):

i assume that you are using datatable in laravel to be flexible but the best way is to load your data in php array loop then fetch your data again in mysql . Goodluck!

Comment: yes, but i need to do it on MySQL for Stored Procedure purpose. and to lessen the process in my frontend side. --- thanks @RaRa